# Waiting for an event-raising thread to cancel

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, cancellation

I have a worker thread that reports progress by raising an event.

```
private volatile bool canRun;

public void Run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count && canRun; i++)
    {
        // do stuff

        OnProgressMade((float)i / (float)count);
    }

    OnWorkFinished();
}

public void Cancel()
{
    canRun = false;

    // wait for the thread to finish
}
```

In the `Cancel` method, I would like to wait for the thread to finish. Otherwise, someone might call `Cancel` and then immediately `Dispose` while the thread is still "doing stuff". If I used `Join`, there might be a deadlock - UI waits for the thread to cancel, thread waits for the UI to handle the `ProgressMade` event.

Is there a way to solve this nicely, or is it bad design from the beginning? My current solution relies on the UI waiting for the `WorkFinished` event before disposing the worker.

Comment: What C# version are you using? With await this is not too hard to do.

Comment: Why not join in the cancel method?

Comment: I think im not catching your drift. If you invoke `Cancel`, then it will exit the loop but still invoke `OnWorkFinished`. What do you not want to Dispose?

Comment: usr: I'm using C# 4.0. I played a bit with `async/await`, but I'm not very confident with it. Do you mean awaiting the `WorkFinished` event and then calling `Dispose`?

Vadim: It causes a deadlock when the worker thread raises the `ProgressMade` event and waits for it to be handled.

Yuval: I want to avoid the situation when the worker is disposed before it leaves the for loop. It reads from a file and `Dispose` closes the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments you hint that you might be able to use await (which is possible even on .NET 4.0). It could look like this:

```
MyWorker w;
CancellationTokenSource cts;

void OnStart(eventargs bla bla) {
 cts = new ...();
 w = new ...(cts.Token);
}

void OnCancel(eventargs bla bla) {
 cts.Cancel();
 await w.WaitForShutdown();
 MsgBox("cancelled");
}
```

And we need to make MyWorker cooperate:

```
class MyWorker {
CancellationToken ct = <from ctor>;
TaskCompletionSource<object> shutdownCompletedTcs = new ...();

public void Run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count && !ct.IsCancellationRequested; i++)
    {
        // do stuff

        OnProgressMade((float)i / (float)count);
    }

    //OnWorkFinished(); //old
    shutdownCompletedTcs.SetResult(null); //new, set "event"
}

public Task WaitForShutdown() {
 return shutdownCompletedTcs.Task;
}
}
```

(Quickly slapped together.) Note, that all wait operations use await. They release the UI thread without interrupting your control flow.

Also note, that `MyWorker` is cooperatively cancellable. It does not know anything about the UI.

Comment: +1: Yup, I'd vote for a cancellation token based approach every single time.